# `querySelectorAll` doesn't return anything in `casperjs`

Tags: javascript, casperjs

Using `casperjs`, I know that I'm able to execute JavaScript in the context of the visited page by using `this.evaluate`. It seems to work well, except that I can't find anything with `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll`, no matter what the starting URL is.

To investigate this, I created two files: `test.html` and `test.js`, serving locally with `python3 -m http.server` on port `8000`. These are the files:

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Page title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>A test to see</p>
    <p>if casperjs can grab elements</p>
    <p>evaluating JS</p>
    <p>in the context of the page</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**test.js**

```
function grabTitle(){
    return document.title;
}

function grabParagraphs(){
    var pars = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    for (var i=0; i<pars.length; i++){
        texts.push(pars[i].textContent);
    }
}

var casper = require("casper").create();
var url = "http://localhost:8000/test.html";
var texts = [];

casper.start(url,function(){
    this.echo("Begin");
});

casper.then(function(){
    var title = this.evaluate(grabTitle);
    this.echo("The title is: " + title);
    this.evaluate(grabParagraphs);
    this.echo(texts.length + " paragraphs found:\n" + texts);
});

casper.run(function(){
    this.echo("Done").exit();
});
```

Running `casperjs test.js` gave me this output:

```
Begin
The title is: Page title
0 paragraphs found:

Done
```

It finds the title, so `grabTitle` works correctly, executing in the context of the page, but no paragraphs are found. I thought that maybe i didn't wait enough for the page to load, so i tried `casper.waitForSelector("p",function(){ ... });` and even `casper.wait(10000,function ... )`, waiting for 10 seconds to let the page load, with no result whatsoever.

Modifying `grabParagraphs` using `document.getElementsByTagName` doesn't work either. I can't figure out what's the problem, every example that I can find showcases the usage of `querySelector`, so it should work.

I'm using `phantomjs 2.1.1` and `casperjs 1.1.4` on `Linux Mint`

**EDIT**

Following the suggestion given  by @Mario Nikolaus, I changed `test.js`: instead of pushing the results to the array `texts` defined in the global context of `test.js`, now I define `texts` in `grabParagraphs` and then return the result:

```
function grabParagraphs(){
    var pars = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
    var texts = [];
    for (var i=0; i<pars.length; i++){
        texts.push(pars[i].textContent);
    }
    return texts;
}

casper.then(function(){
    var title = this.evaluate(grabTitle);
    this.echo("The title is: "+title);
    var texts = this.evaluate(grabParagraphs);
    this.echo(texts.length+" paragraphs found:\n"+texts)
});
```

Originally I assumed that I could push the results in the variable `texts` because, since it was defined in the context of `test.js`, it was globally available. However, it isn't available *in the context of the page*, so that was the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning value from evaluate in your `grabParagraphs` function.

Create another array variable within the browser context, return that array to you casper context and assign it to array.

```
function grabTitle(){
  return document.title;
}

function grabParagraphs(){
  var arr = [];
  var pars = document.querySelectorAll("p");
  for (var i=0; i<pars.length; i++){
      arr.push(pars[i].textContent);
  }
  return arr;
}

var casper = require("casper").create();
var url = "http://localhost:8001/a.html";

casper.start(url,function(){
  this.echo("Begin");
});

casper.then(function(){
  var title = this.evaluate(grabTitle);
  this.echo("The title is: " + title);
  var texts = this.evaluate(grabParagraphs);
  this.echo(texts.length + " paragraphs found:\n" + texts);
});

casper.run(function(){
  this.echo("Done").exit();
});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Bingo!  That was the problem, I thought `texts` was availble "inside" the context of the page, what a silly mistake